# table view height with variable

Tags: ios, uitableview

Good day! I have a table view and i want to set table view height like this:

```
detailViewController = [[Contacts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Contacts" bundle:nil];

float height = 44*[[detailViewController contactList] count];

CGRect viewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 50.0f, 250.0f, height);

[detailViewController.tableView setFrame: viewFrame];

MainViewController *mainView = (MainViewController*)app.viewController;

for (UIView *theView in mainView.currenWeatherView.subviews) {
    [theView removeFromSuperview];
}

[mainView.currenWeatherView addSubview: detailViewController.tableView];
```

but i does not work, height is like one screen or something like this.

```
float height = 44*[[detailViewController contactList] count];
height = 10580;
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Normally you don't set tableview's height based on content. You just set fixed frame for tableview and let tableview manage the rest. Tableview is a subclass of scrollview, so if you have more content, tableview will scroll for you to show the other cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't change frame size. use

```
 [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.contentSize.width, heightOfTable)];
```